# ovs-ofctl queue-stats command not working and I cannot find ovs-vswitchd.log file

Tags: queue, openvswitch, qos

now I'm using ovs 2.4.0, and I made queues in Qos and stuck it to port.

I can check queue list using `ovs-vsctl list queue` command, 
and I can also watch `ovsdb-tool show-log` command's result.(all queue is generated already.)

I checked the `ovsdb-client dump` result, and I can see port-qos-queue were stuck very well.

But I cannot see the queue info through `ovs-ofctl queue-stats (bridge) (port)` command, it just returns there's no queue on port.

I searched all results, but I cannot find how to solve the prob.

ovs-vswitchd.log file is not in here.(I search file through `find / -name *.log`)
I don't know what's the command that makes log file.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run openvswitchd with "--verbose" parameter.

Regards.